# Resistors for xilinx coolrunner ii cpld pcb

Tags: xilinx, jtag, programmable-logic

I am making a pcb which contains among others a coolrunner ii cpld .

I will programm the CPLD through jtag from a digilent cpld  development board .

I read in a xilinx application note that pull-up resistors of 4.7k should be placed on each one of the  jtag pins .

Are series current limiting resistors also required on the traces of the pins ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No more than 100 ohms. Try a 75 ohm or 33.2 ohm series resistor on the JTAG signals. These resistors aren't really for current limiting, they are just going to help with reducing reflections. You should place them close to the driver on that signal.